# cat * command in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, kernel, cat

What does cat * command do in Linux Terminal?
I used it along with a file-name

```
cat * file-name
```

I got a large output, with lots of garbage characters and proper formatted text. Towards the end I felt it was the kernel configuration parameters and at last was my file. I am guessing it is the ram content, that was displayed. Is that right?

Comment: You should just 'cat file-name' ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The * character is interepreted as a *wildcard* by your shell. This means you pass *every* file and directory (except hidden ones) to `cat`. So what you are seeing is not the content of your RAM but the content of all files of your current directory.

Answer (score 3):

This command should be equivalent to the following commands:

```
cat first-file-in-current-directory
cat second-file-in-current-directory
   ...
cat last-file-in-current-directory
cat file-name
```

This means: It shows the content of all files in the current directory and then the file whose name is given.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter cat * on the shell, the interpreter will understand the meta character symbol * to "all available" and execute based on the command given,

in our scenario we use cat * so the all available file will listed on the scree based on its "ls" commands output,

```
 [root@ranjith test]# ls
 four.txt  one.txt  three.txt  two.txt

 [root@ranjith test]# cat one.txt
 1
 [root@ranjith test]# cat two.txt
 2
 [root@ranjith test]# cat three.txt
 3
 [root@ranjith test]# cat four.txt
 4
 [root@ranjith test]# cat *
 4
 1
 3
 2
```

If any directory found on the path it will shows like "cat: dir_name: Is a directory"

Thanks.